# CSS grid issue: I can't make the outer grid container fill the entire page

Tags: html, css, reactjs, layout, css-grid

I'm sure this is a trivial (and perhaps stuid) issue, but I can't get it to work.

I'm trying to use css grid in my react project, but for some reason, there is a huge margin outside of the outer container, and I don't know how to remove it.

Here's the html:

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="header">HEADER</div>
    <div className="menu">MENU</div>
    <div className="content">CONTENT</div>
    <div className="extra">EXTRA</div>
    <div className="footer">FOOTER</div>
 </div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
  grid-template-areas:
  ". h h h h h h h h h h h"
  "m c c c c c c c c c e e"
  "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
  grid-template-areas: ". h h h h h h h h h h h" "m c c c c c c c c c e e" "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
}
```

```html
<div className="container">
  <div className="header">HEADER</div>
  <div className="menu">MENU</div>
  <div className="content">CONTENT</div>
  <div className="extra">EXTRA</div>
  <div className="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like: 
[image: snapshot]

I tried to manage the margin: `margin: 0` in several ways, and increase the width `width: 100%`, but nothing works. Additionally, when I remove the margin, it moves the content to the start, and I cannot move it with either `justify-content: center` or `justify-self: center`.

I'm using react as well, but I'm only rendering this component, and outer div it returns is the `.container` div.

Thank you.

EDIT: I found a bootstrap import in a react file that was rendering this component, which was the issue. Sorry. *facepalm*. So using `width: 100vw` as suggested actually worked.

Comment: remove justify-content if it's there. else what about the parent of `.container` styling ?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica the `className` is a React convention, so that's not the case. But I'll see if I can add more context. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using create-react-app then remove the css that come along with create-react-app.

Else try

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
  grid-template-areas: ". h h h h h h h h h h h" "m c c c c c c c c c e e" "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
}
```

Comment: This made it a bit wider, but for some reason there still were a margin attached to the `.container` div.
However, I found a bootstrap import in the React file that rendered the component, which was causing the issue. Your suggestion on the react css file made med look for this. I'm sorry for the trouble! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This fills the whole browser. Note the width:100vw rather than width:100vh:

```
<div style="width:100vw; height:100vh ; background-color: red;"></div>
```